# admob ads not refreshing on window's phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I have implemented admob into my window phone 7 app. The ad is showing fine. But for some reasons, it does not refresh. So the same ad would stay on the screen for as long as the user uses the app.

I have checked my admob page, the refresh rate is set to every 20 secs or so.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Here is how I implemented admob:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7.WPF;assembly=Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7">
```

and

```
<my:BannerAd AdUnitID="a1508671d491d11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-15,0,0" Name="bannerAd1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="480" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: am not able to see any adds in my app (tested in wp7 device), and it showing blank screen any idea? suggest me

Comment: can u please help me to solve my problem

Comment: Did you check on the admob side whether a request for ads is received?

Comment: thanx for replay :) am very new to wp7 development can you please tell me how to check that

Comment: Login into admob website, in the Sites and Apps tab, have a look at the Status whehter it has turned green (live) and the number of requests.

Comment: yeah green light showing and number of requests is 15 :) and i just added dll reference , BannerAd in my xaml

Comment: i mean i need to make request programmatically??? or any thing else to do ??

Comment: This is the tutorial I have followed: http://winphone.ca/articles/tutorial-ads-and-your-windows-phone-app-part-2-admob/ The code I quoted in the question was what I put in my app.

Comment: yeah that part i did but am not able to see the ads( i didn't get any errors) and why you added  `DataContext="{Binding}"`

Comment: Did you check the position of the ad banner (make sure it is on the screen), also whether there is something blocking/on top of the banner.

Comment: no i have only this control in my screen and that sample project comes from SDK also not working :(

Comment: @Telkitty ads are not refreshing for me also did you slove this?? please replay me

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the AdFailed event and see if it is failing to load?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new ad unit after a specified interval. That would be a workaround of this problem, but not a solution.

```
            AdView bannerAd = new AdView
            {
                Format = AdFormats.Banner,
                AdUnitID = "MY_AD_UNIT_ID"  // Replace your AD Unit ID 
            };
            bannerAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            bannerAd.FailedToReceiveAd += OnFailedToReceiveAd;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(bannerAd);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            adRequest.ForceTesting = true;
            bannerAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
```